# Python web scraping returning with records- Stock Update

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have been doing my web scraping project with this web link. But the code runs with no errors. But its ot showing any records. Can you pls check the reason for the same?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://live-cosmos.finq.com/trading-platform/#trading/Shares/Global/USA/All/FACEBOOK"
data  = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Instrument", "Sell", "Buy", "Change"])
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    col = row.find_all("td")
    Instrument = col[0].text
    Sell = col[1].text
    Buy = col[2].text
    Change = col[3].text
    df = df.append({"Instrument":Instrument,"Sell":Sell,"Buy":Buy,"Change":Change}, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Thanks

Comment: Opening the link in web-browser it seems that you need to be logged-in first to get any information.

Comment: Did you try to `print(data)` and look what elements are actually there? Frequently changing data like stock prices are written to the html with javascript. Beautifulsoup doesn't run Javascript

Comment: This approach won'nt work because as @AndrejKesely mentions you need to be logged in. So either use `Selenium` to automate the login process or check in your browser whether the data is retrieved from an api that you can access directly.

Comment: Hi all, yes i have to log in actually to do this kind of scraping. Can you tell me how to automate the log in process using selenium?

Comment: You can find many tutorials about this, you could check [this one](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/automate-login-to-websites-using-selenium-in-python) for example. Once you have retrieved the source code of the relevant page you can pass it to BeautifulSoup, although you can also extract content with Selenium